# The first item number displays on the far right but all others float left, how do I get the 1 where it should be?

Tags: javascript, css, css-float, html-lists

The [link](http://phscweb.com/JS/khall/assets/files/js/8-5/index.htm) is the project I have been working on. The problem I'm having is that the first item that is added to the list shows the number 1 on the far right side when it should be floating left like the rest of the list items that are added. If someone could point me in the right direction I could maybe figure it out. Just need a little bump.

```css
/*  JavaScript 6th Edition
    Chapter 8
    Hands-on Project 8-4

    Filename: styles.css
*/

/* apply a natural box layout model to all elements */
* {
   -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
   -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
   box-sizing: border-box;
}

/* reset rules */
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
   border: 0;
   font-size: 100%;
   font: inherit;
   vertical-align: baseline;
}

/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
   display: block;
}

body {
   line-height: 1;
   width: 600px;
   background: white;
   margin: 0 auto;
   font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; 
}

ol, ul {
   list-style: none;
}

/* page header */
header {
   background: #FFC340;
   width: 100%;
   color: black;
   font-size: 48px;
   text-align: center;
   line-height: 1.5em;
   border-bottom: 1px solid black;
   border-left: 1px solid black;
   border-right: 1px solid black;
}

/* main content */
article {
   text-align: left;
   background: white;
   overflow: auto;
   border-bottom: 1px solid black;
   border-left: 1px solid black;
   border-right: 1px solid black;
}

article h2 {
   font-weight: bold;
   font-size: 24px;
   padding: 1em;
   padding-bottom: 0;
   float: left;
}

div {
   padding: 1em;
   border: none;
   text-align: left;
}

div p {
   font-weight: bold;
   margin-bottom: 0.4em;
}

ol {
   list-style-type: decimal;
   padding-left: 1em;
}

li {
   margin: 0 0 1em 1em;
}

li span.first {
   background: green;
   color: white;
   padding: 2px 5px;
   margin-right: 3px;
   -moz-border-radius: 5px;
   -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
   border-radius: 5px;
}

li span.last {
   background: red;
   color: white;
   padding: 2px 5px;
   margin-right: 3px;
   -moz-border-radius: 5px;
   -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
   border-radius: 5px;
}

/* form */
form {
   background: white;
   padding: 5px;
   float: left;
  }

fieldset {
   padding: 1em;
   border: none;
}

input {
   font-size: 1em;
   float: left;
   margin: 0 auto;
}

#newItem {
   width: 15em;
}

label {
   display: block;
   font-weight: bold;
   text-align: left;
}

input, label, button {
   margin: 5px 10px;
}
```

```html
<article>
    <h2>To Do List</h2>
    <form>
        <fieldset>
            <input type="text" id="newItem">
            <input type="button" id="button" value="Add Item">
        </fieldset>
    </form>
    <div id="results">
        <ol><li><span class="first">first</span><span class="last">last</span></li><li><span class="first">first</span><span class="last">last</span></li><li><span class="first">first</span><span class="last">last</span></li><li><span class="first">first</span><span class="last">last</span></li></ol>
    </div>
</article>
```

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link to the site 
that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value to future visitors once 
the problem is solved or if the site you're linking to is inaccessible. Posting a 
[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (MCVE)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that 
demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, see 
[Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) 
Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply, I would like to add the code but I'm not sure where the problem lies. The program functions as it should, it just displays the first item in the wrong place. Should I post the .CSS? Thanks for the reply.

Comment: @Kyle Any relevant CSS, HTML or JavaScript that would affect the positioning of these elements. Only meaningful code, please (not 15 different CSS classes)

Comment: Which browser are you experiencing this in? I've checked in the current version of Mozilla Firefox/Windows 7 and it seems to be perfectly working.

Comment: When you work to post a minimal example in your question it also helps you debug the issue. You should post the smallest amount of code that reproduces the issue, in your case the HTML, CSS, and JavaScript.

Comment: More than the link please try to add your code here , which will help other to understanding the question in future.

Comment: I just added a Code Snippet providing the code from you link. Unfortunately I added a typo at the bottom of HTML `²` which I can't edit anymore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because the form is floated.

If you remove the float (which is probaby unnecessary) the first list item number appears in the right place.

Comment: Removing the float solved my problem. *face palm* Thanks for the help!

Comment: This solution can have an impact on the layout, as the form now behaves like a standard block level element, as opposed to a floating block level element before.

Answer (score 2):

Try adding this:

```
#results { clear: left; }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your css file `styles.css`.

Change your css class definition to the below.

```
/* form */
form {
   background: white;
   padding: 5px;
}
```

**DEMO :**

```css
        
        /*  JavaScript 6th Edition
    Chapter 8
    Hands-on Project 8-4

    Filename: styles.css
*/

/* apply a natural box layout model to all elements */
* {
   -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
   -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
   box-sizing: border-box;
}

/* reset rules */
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
   border: 0;
   font-size: 100%;
   font: inherit;
   vertical-align: baseline;
}

/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
   display: block;
}

body {
   line-height: 1;
   width: 600px;
   background: white;
   margin: 0 auto;
   font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; 
}

ol, ul {
   list-style: none;
}

/* page header */
header {
   background: #FFC340;
   width: 100%;
   color: black;
   font-size: 48px;
   text-align: center;
   line-height: 1.5em;
   border-bottom: 1px solid black;
   border-left: 1px solid black;
   border-right: 1px solid black;
}

/* main content */
article {
   text-align: left;
   background: white;
   overflow: auto;
   border-bottom: 1px solid black;
   border-left: 1px solid black;
   border-right: 1px solid black;
}

article h2 {
   font-weight: bold;
   font-size: 24px;
   padding: 1em;
   padding-bottom: 0;
   float: left;
}

div {
   padding: 1em;
   border: none;
   text-align: left;
}

div p {
   font-weight: bold;
   margin-bottom: 0.4em;
}

ol {
   list-style-type: decimal;
   padding-left: 1em;
}

li {
   margin: 0 0 1em 1em;
}

li span.first {
   background: green;
   color: white;
   padding: 2px 5px;
   margin-right: 3px;
   -moz-border-radius: 5px;
   -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
   border-radius: 5px;
}

li span.last {
   background: red;
   color: white;
   padding: 2px 5px;
   margin-right: 3px;
   -moz-border-radius: 5px;
   -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
   border-radius: 5px;
}

/* form */
form {
   background: white;
   padding: 5px;
  }

fieldset {
   padding: 1em;
   border: none;
}

input {
   font-size: 1em;
   float: left;
   margin: 0 auto;
}

#newItem {
   width: 15em;
}

label {
   display: block;
   font-weight: bold;
   text-align: left;
}

input, label, button {
   margin: 5px 10px;
}
```

```html
<article>
    <h2>To Do List</h2>
    <form>
        <fieldset>
            <input type="text" id="newItem">
            <input type="button" id="button" value="Add Item">
        </fieldset>
    </form>
    <div id="results">
        <ol><li><span class="first">first</span><span class="last">last</span></li><li><span class="first">first</span><span class="last">last</span></li><li><span class="first">first</span><span class="last">last</span></li><li><span class="first">first</span><span class="last">last</span></li></ol>
    </div>
</article>
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned before, the problem is the floating elements not being cleared above the list.

To fix this, simply insert `<br clear="left" />` between your `<form>` and your `<ol>`.

https://jsfiddle.net/nLpqzua9/1/

If you want to avoid unnecessary additional markup, apply `clear: left;` on the `div#results`.

https://jsfiddle.net/nLpqzua9/2/

Comment: There's no need for adding a break element when the clear can be added to the list.

Comment: Added the pure CSS solution (which is better).